# A simpler way to understand the isomorphism: $H_0(X) \cong \tilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to figure out the below sentence (in bold, starting with "since.." from Hatcher formally:

> ...This is done by defining the reduced homology groups $\tilde{H}_n(X)$ to be the homology groups of the augmented chain complex
> $$
>  \cdots \to C_2(X) \overset{\partial_2}{\to} C_1(X) \overset{\partial_1}{\to} C_0 \overset{\epsilon}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to 0
> $$
> [where $\epsilon(\sigma) = 1$ for all singular 0-simplices $\sigma$]...
>
> **Since $\epsilon\partial_1 = 0$, $\epsilon$ vanishes on $\operatorname{Im}{\partial_1}$ and hence induces a map $H_0(X) \to \mathbb{Z}$ with kernel $\tilde{H}(X)$, so $H_0(X) \cong \tilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$**.

I know that this sentence, and the isomorphism at then end, appear in quite a few questions (e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831546/definition-of-reduced-homology), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55399/reduced-homology?rq=1)), but either the answers seem to be too intuition-based  or the responders seem to employ more advanced tools like splits, which I am not familiar with.

**EDIT**: I also find it slightly odd that Hatcher provides a section on "Exact sequences" on page 113, yet the aforementioned quote is from p. 110.

**My main issue is with understand why the isomorphism holds, without going into splits** **(I am familiar, however, with the classic isomorphism theorems if that can help). Any advice here would be greatly appreciated!**

Also - what is the importance of this discussion? Why should we care about this isomorphism?

Comment: You'll need to develop a very solid understanding of the algebra of commutative groups, including properties of homomorphisms and their kernels and images, and properties of quotients, induced homomorphisms under quotients, split exact sequences, etc. Without that, Hatcher is rapidly going to become impossible to understand.

Comment: Part of the reason why you might find those various answers to be "too intuition-based" is that the answers are freely applying all of those algebraic prerequisites.

Comment: A "splitting" is a way of showing that an abelian group is isomorphic to a direct sum, along with identifying the summands. So it is a natural tool to use here (and not that complicated).

Comment: Why should we care? Some theorems will be more conveniently stated for ordinary homology, some for reduced homology. It is therefore very useful to know that you can easily compute one once you know the other.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks - it seems that neither Dummit and Foote nor Herstein are sufficient (nothing about split exact sequences) - are you able to point to a good resources that would include such more advanced topics?

Comment: @LeeMosher Actually, I can see there's a section on split exact sequences in Dummit and Foote, but if there are any good resources that pop into mind  - would appreciate knowing.

Comment: @Anon another (first-year graduate) algebra text that includes stuff on exact sequences that's a pretty popular reference is Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0," which gets to exact sequences of modules rather quickly (compared to something like Dummit and Foote). A module over the integers is the same thing as an abelian group, and the book is pretty focused on constructions with modules over commutative rings such as homomorphisms, kernels, images, quotients, exact sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not a precise duplicate of other questions, but I think it is useful to look at

- [Definition of $\tilde{H}_n(X,A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098995/definition-of-tildeh-nx-a/4099024#4099024)
- [Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and $x_0\in X$. Prove that $\widetilde{H_n}(X)=H_n(X,x_0)$ for all $n\geq 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281300)
- [Clarification about reduced Homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3666124)

> I also find it slightly odd that Hatcher provides a section on "Exact sequences" on page 113, yet the aforementioned quote is from p. 110.

Hatcher introdces both (ordinary) homology groups and reduced homology groups before he introduces the concept of exactness. Why should this be a problem? One has to define homology groups and induced homomorphisms (in the section "Homotopy Invariance" on p. 110 / 111) before one can study its properties.

> My main issue is with understand why the isomorphism holds, without going into splits.

I do not think that the classic isomorphism theorems will help you to understand why the exactness of
$$0 \to \tilde{H}_0(X) \stackrel{\iota}{\to} H_0(X) \stackrel{\pi}{\to} \mathbb Z \to 0$$
implies
$$H_0(X) \approx \tilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \mathbb Z . \tag{1} $$
So let us give a proof. It uses the *concept* of splitting a short exact sequence, but it avoids to use the *word* splitting.

Since $\pi$ is surjective, there exists $g \in H_0(X)$ such that $\pi(g) = 1$. Define $s : \mathbb Z \to H_0(X)$ by $s(n) = ng$. This is a group homomorphism such that $\pi \circ s = id$. Next define
$$\phi : \tilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \mathbb Z \to H_0(X), \phi(a,n) = \iota(a) + s(n) .$$
This is a group homomorphism.

1. $\phi$ is injective.

Let $\phi(a_1,n_1) = \phi(a_2,n_2)$. Noting that $\pi \circ \iota = 0$, we get $$n_i = \pi(s(n_i))) = \pi(\iota(a_i)) + \pi(s(n_i))) = \pi(\iota(a_i)) + \pi(s(n_i)) = \pi(\phi(a_i,n_i)) .$$
Thus $n_1 = n_2$ and therefore $\iota(a_1) = \iota(a_2)$. Since $\iota$ is injective, $a_1 = a_2$.

2. $\phi$ is surjective.

Let $h \in H_0(X)$. Set $n = \pi(h)$. Then $\pi(h - s(n)) = \pi(h) - \pi(s(n)) = n - n = 0$, thus $h - s(n) \in \ker \pi = \operatorname{im} \iota$, i.e. $h - s(n) = \iota(a)$ for some $a \in \tilde{H}_0(X)$. This shows $\phi(a,n) = h$.

> Why should we care about this isomorphism?

This is philosophical question. Let us first observe that the above isomorphism $\phi$ depends on the *choice* of $g \in H_0(X)$ such that $\pi(g) = 1$. Thus $\phi$ is no *canonical isomorphism*. However, $(1)$ says that there is a *transparent relationship* between $H_0(X)$ and $\tilde{H}_0(X)$; this is not a priori obvious.

Intuitively it means that each $H_0(X)$ contains a trivial summand $\mathbb Z$ which comes from the group $Z = H_0(*) \approx \mathbb Z$ of the one-point space $*$. Note that $Z$ embeds into $H_0(X)$ via $\mu_* : H_0(*) \to H_0(X)$, where $\mu : * \to X$ is any map. Again this map involves the choice of a point $x_0 \in X$ with $\mu(*) = \{x_0\}$, and thus it is not a canonical map. The constant map $c : X \to *$ has the property $c \circ \mu = id$, thus $c_* \circ \mu_* = id$ which shows that $\mu_*$ is an injection.

Concerning the concept of *augmentation map* which is used in the definition of reduced homology also have a look at

- [The boundary of a $singular\; 0-simplex$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4355056)
- [Definition of zeroth homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4333707)

*Remark.*

The fact that the isomorphism $\phi$ depends on the choice of $g \in \pi^{-1}(1)$ does not imply the **non-existence** of a canonical isomorphism (or more formally: *natural isomorphism*)  $\tilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \mathbb Z \to H_0(X)$. The non-existence is proved in [Isomorphism not natural in $X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4344687)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You are right, the dependence on the choice of $g$ is only an indication. The non-existence of a canonical isomorphism requires a proof. See my update.

Comment: Having read through split exact sequences and the splitting lemma, I'm now convinced that the simplest way to prove this is, in fact, using the notion of split exact sequences and the splitting lemma (which, if I'm not mistaken, is what helps show the isomorphism). This response is helping me complete some of the missing details in the other posts. Thanks!